# Spring beans (business layer) in separate module

Tags: java, spring, ejb

I'm starting new application. I would like to have all business logic and domain classes separeted in standalone module (something like remote EJB). This is because of the app will have at least two (later more may be) clients - Desktop, Web (Spring MVC).

Is this possible with Spring? Or should I use EJB and Spring only for MVC in web app client?

Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.  You'll either put the resulting jar as a library in your full application, or host is separately and use some remoting system (hessian, soap, rmi, ...) to interface between them.  Spring can help with that as well.

Comment: It depends on the type of app.  If you're sure you will have a lot of different interfaces, then I would certainly create the web interface as a separate application.  If you're not sure about this, I would just create a simple Spring webapp.  If you keep the interface clean, you can still pull out the web tier later.